# Got Null value during passing data from fragments to Activity

Tags: android, android-intent, bundle, android-fragmentactivity

I'm working with fragments and encounter with a following problem :

1. While passing data from fragments i used bundle to pass integer
   values and sending them through intent.
2. I'm calling them by using intent .
3. But while i'm printing then i'm getting only **Null** values.

From `fragment`:

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putInt("myData", x);
Intent in=new Intent(getActivity(),B.class);
in.putExtra("xy", bundle);
startActivity(in);
```

In `Activity`:

```
Intent in=getIntent();
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
int value = bundle.getInt("myData");
Log.v("in mainactivity",""+value);
```

Here it getting Null values.
I hope u understand the problem.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to use (note the s at the end of the `putExtra`**s**)

```
 in.putExtras(bundle);
```

otherwise you can not directly retrieve it with  `getIntent().getExtras();`

Comment: awsomee...IQ thanq soo muchhhhh

Comment: why we not use `Intent.putExtra` for passing data between components ?

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK we can. I was only pointing out that if he want to retrieve the bundle with getExtras he has to use the putExtras. Your answer is correct as my (sorry for the misunderstanding)

Comment: Hi guys....thanx for your answer..I want to ask you another question...hope u guys can help me for this....Thnaq so much for sharing your technical skills....you can refer this link....http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16805678/fragment-was-unable-to-replace-with-fragment-in-viewpager

Answer (score 2):

if you are passing `Bundle` using `Intent.putExtra` then get it as in second Activity :

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getBundleExtra("xy");   //<< get Bundle from Intent

int value = bundle.getInt("myData");//<extract values from Bundle using key
```

Comment: Hi guys....thanx for your answer..I want to ask you another question...hope u guys can help me for this....Thnaq so much for sharing your technical skills....you can refer this link....stackoverflow.com/questions/16805678/…

Answer (score 1):

instead of:

```
 Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putInt("myData", x);
                Intent in=new Intent(getActivity(),B.class);
                in.putExtra("xy", bundle);
                startActivity(in);
```

you can simply pass data by:

```
            Intent in=new Intent(getActivity(),B.class);
            in.putExtra("myData", x);
            startActivity(in);
```

Comment: Hi guys....thanx for your answer..I want to ask you another question...hope u guys can help me for this....Thnaq so much for sharing your technical skills....you can refer this link....stackoverflow.com/questions/16805678/…

Answer (score 0):

I think the following link can help you.

http://laaptu.wordpress.com/tag/android-passing-data-from-activity-to-fragment/