# Growout/shrink/fadeout animation in android

Tags: android, animation, android-animation

I got a problem with animation....
My problem is....
1.If you see the image i have given below you can understand that i have a button and a image view in screen.
2.In the first screen I have a button and a  image-view.
3.If i click on the button it should move to gallery.
4.If i select a image if you see the other screens....like that at first image should cover the screen and slowly it should grow-out and just like last screen it should automatically should be placed on image-view.
This is my problem...I tried with scale but unable to fulfill the task..Suggestions from you are more valuable......If it seems the question is incomplete please let me know.. thank you...

scale.xml.

```
<set android:shareInterpolator="false"    
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<scale
android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"
android:fromXScale="10"
android:toXScale="1.4"
android:fromYScale="10"
android:toYScale="1.4"
android:pivotX="50%"
android:pivotY="50%"

android:duration="1000" />
```

after selecting the image from gallery.....i started animation but its not working finee

[image]

Comment: ya i have added a snippet

Comment: can you define *not working fine*?